# Android Studio crashes with large C++ header file

Tags: c++, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to use NDK with Android Studio to compile my C++ code.
Inside my C++ code, I have a couple of image data header which stored very large unsigned char array. I can compile the code with standalone NDK without any problem.

However inside Android studio, if I include those image data header files, Android studio will be freezing with 100% CPU load.

Is there a setting I missing inside Android Studio? How should I solve this problem? I want to compile the code inside Android Studio, so I can step through inside the C++ code. And, the image data should be compiled inside the program (not a separate file).

[image: Begin of Unsigned char array of Image Data]
[image]

**Updated**

For now, I tried to used #pragma once inside the cpp before the include header (instead of defining inside the headers), and it would work. But if I put include guards or #pragma once inside the header, Android Studio will still freeze. I don't understand why pragma once and include guards not works if I put inside the headers.

[image: pragma one]

Comment: Is it actually freezing ? did  you let it compile sufficiently long (24 hours) ?

Comment: How big is *very large* exactly? 97000 lines of array data is pretty enormous, and you've said *a couple*. What sort of memory hog are you writing for Android?

Comment: The header file is 7.3MB with 1  unsigned char array

Comment: You might be including another header that's including the current header without using `#pragma once` or other guards.

Comment: And, I have 2 of those header files. I haven't use #pragma once. I will try it out now

Comment: If I add #pragma one/ include guards inside the header file, Android Studio will still freeze.

Comment: Have you filed a bug?

Comment: Yes, I have filed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I solved the problem. 
Instead of define the char array on the header file.
I move the char array to cpp file and create a global.h header, which looks like this. Android Studio will not freeze now.

global.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

    extern const unsigned char image_data1[];
    extern const unsigned char image_data2[];

#endif // GLOBAL_H
```